# Jenkins - Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags

Tags: jenkins

While running job through Jenkins. i'm getting this error:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project arebenefitsavailable-api-atdd: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two dependencies in pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
        </dependency>
 
 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```